# Rendezvous with Ray

Tags: etymology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, phonology, subcontinental-english

Rendezvous  is  one  of  the  English  words  whose  pronunciation  is  nothing  to   do   with  its   spelling  .I  have  come  across the  word  in the lesson **Rendezvous with  Ray**
I have  understood  its  meaning  and  pronunciation.It  is  a  French    word  with  an  English  spelling. It  is  one  of  the  most  mispronounced  words  in  countries  like  India.

> **What is the  one  word that   rhymes  with  Rendezvous and what  could  be the  possible  reason for  its  peculiar  pronunciation?**

Here  are  two links  which  helped  me  to  know  about  Rendezvous pronunciation in India and  native  English speaking  countries especially  in  England

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/rendezvous

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-hindi/rendezvous

Comment: The only difference between the French and English spelling is that the French word is hyphenated : _rendez-vous_. It's simply a borrowed word.

Comment: Because English.

Comment: Closed as too broad because you have asked two questions. Asking for a list is not a good fit for Stack Exchange. You have no evidence of research — *rendezvous* is a **French** word, albeit with a specific meaning which has been adopted into English. It would probably help to know how it's pronounced in Indian English, which you haven't stated.

Comment: Do you feel safe in the café after they broke the karaoke machine?  They learned to cater at their alma mater (they went back later), but (entre nous) the sous chef was replaced in a coup because they didn’t like the soup.  I hoped to get a moped.  Have you got a bon mot for that, or are you not too hot? — English is full of words that are borrowed from other languages and are pronounced as they are in the source language.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  Meanwhile, as Hot Licks says, English pronunciation is no bed of roses.  “choose” rhymes with “lose”, “whose”, “cruise” and “snooze”.  “choose” doesn’t rhyme with “caboose”, “goose”, “loose” and “moose”.  “chose” rhymes with “nose”, “pose” and “rose” (but not “lose”).  Meanwhile, “dose” rhymes with “cellulose” and “sucrose” (and “gross”) but not “lose” or “rose”, and “floss” doesn’t rhyme with “gross”.  “close” has two pronunciations — it can rhyme with “dose” or with “nose”.  And then there’s “purpose”, which (approximately) rhymes with “campus”, “pompous” and “porous”. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  “come” rhymes with “from”.  “come” doesn’t rhyme with “home”, and “from” doesn’t rhyme with “mom”, “ROM” and “Tom”.  Americans and Brits pronounce ‘‘route’’ differently.  And don’t get me started on “GIF” and “ough”.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the reason why the pronunciation of *rendezvous* in English approximates the French pronunciation and does not sound the *z* of *rendez* and the *s* of *vous* might be that when English-speaking people are taught the rudiments of French, they learn that *vous*, a high frequency pronoun, is pronounced /vu/ (I leave aside liaison of *vous* with a following vowel where *vous* is realized as /vuz/) and *ez* as a conjugation ending is /e/.  So when the word was borrowed from French into English, that basic knowledge of French checked any egregious mispronunciation of the /rɒndeɪzvu:z/ type

We have a more vexed issue in the spelling of *rendezvous* used as a verb:

- I rendezvous /rɒndeɪvu:/
- You rendezvous /rɒndeɪvu:/
- He/she ??? /rɒndeɪvu:z/

Comment: The word is [*rendezvouses*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/rendezvouses)

Comment: @Lordology  Unless I'm mistaken, the link you provide gives "rendezvous" , pronounced /u:z/ as the third person singular conjugation of the simple present.

Comment: You're right; it says one thing and gives me another.  Maybe it is just *rendezvous* for third person present.

Comment: [Or maybe not?  I am confused.](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/rendezvouses#English)